# Interface with only constants

Tags: java, interface

Recently I came across a piece of code wherein I found an interface with **only** constants. And those constants were accessed in classes using static imports. The constants were more in number (around 30 to 50).

Personally, I don't think it's a good practice. Thats why its called as Constant Interface Antipattern according to Effective Java. I don't find any good reason to go for this kind of coding.

Also, static import should be used ONLY if there are few constants to be imported by many classes in our application.

Can anyone of you please let me know if there are any other good reasons to go for constants only interface?

Comment: Its not great, but often there isn't a simpler way to collect lots of constants.  What would you consider to be the alternative? (often that is worse ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey We use constants interface for jdbc stored procedure names. Is that a good exception or still a case of bad practice?

Comment: If all the names have a same type and they are all of the same sort of information, then @Suraj's suggestion of using an `enum` is better.  However, in my experience, most interface constants are more a random collection of magic numbers you want to share between classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly prior to the introduction of enums, if you had a large collection of constants that needed to be shared between a number of classes, a Constant Interface was probably the most pragmatic way to do so.

If those constants were only used in one class then the comments in other answers ('a pattern to avoid') are quite valid - they would be most useful if declared by the class that uses them.

With newer versions of Java, I'd move towards enums with a constructor that allows value(s) to be set. However it's still the case that if the set of values are only used by a single class, it makes most sense to declare them within that class rather than separately.

Comment: Recently I ran across a enum that had a line with a single semi-colon it and it lacked a package-private constructor (as you would usually see with a enum).  So, the user was putting public static final vars in that enum but it seems that they might as well just use an interface if that is all they are going to do.  Or is there a better way?   Why use an enum if they aren't going to use the instance constructor of the enum?

Answer (score 3):

If those constants make some logical grouping, then I could use an **enum** instead

Comment: What does using an enum gain you?  How does this work if the constants have different types?

Comment: enum gives you so so much. For this particular example, "type safety" will be a big takeaway. If you know the constant interface antipattern, then you know that one of the downside of using interface constant is that "the incidental run-time artifacts have little practical purpose ", enum as a runtime artifact has a lot of goodness

Comment: @PeterLawrey "How does this work if the constants have different types"? If they all form a part of some logical grouping then, you make your type itself of enum

Comment: I am a bit lost by your reply.  say you have some constants `int MIN = 0; int MAX = 100; String INVALID = "Invalid"; byte NL = 10;` How is using an `enum` going to add goodness to these constants?

Comment: ok, do they make a logical grouping?. If NO, then use two separate enums, if YES, then create a enum with a field for each type, and where you are actually using it change the logic to use enum instead of int or string

Comment: BTW: @Liviu has given an example of where an `enum` is probibly a better choice. ;)

Comment: They have a logic grouping in the sense that they are the shared magic numbers for a small number of classes. I wouldn't want to create one enum class per constant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "How is using an enum going to add goodness to these constants?" enum does not adds goodness to constants in terms of type safety. For e.g. if u have a int constant, then the client could pass even negative values although you expect only predefined constants. But its not so in case of conventional constants. But i meant goodness in terms of runtime artifact. ie. you can use relfection or anything runtime over this enum

Comment: You can use reflection over interface constants too. They can all be different types as well. enums have a purpose and replace some previous uses of interface constants, but if you have been using enums effectively you will find you still have constants which are not improved by the use of enums.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Yes you can, but semantically does an interface with constants only, provide any useful artifact during runtime? Think like this, suppose you have a method that takes this interface as a parameter, does it make sense No! But if the same method takes our enum as parameter then it makes sense right :)

Comment: @Suraj, Based on the example I gave, how would you change the method `work(int min, int max, String msg, byte newLine)` which takes `work(MIN, MAX, INVALID, NL)` to use enums.  Would you turn every different constant into an enum and turn one line of code each into a new class?  In any case, most of my constants are used directly and not passed as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this idiom at all.  Why should you separate constants from the context in which they're used?  I find it confusing.

This design forces a class that wants one constant to implement an entire interface that's chock full of them.  And all those constants are public.

The enum idea is a good one.  Anything other than this.

Answer (score 1):

A common alternative is to define public static final constants in a utility class rather than an interface. Take your constants interface, redefine it as a class, put "public static final" on each declaration, and reference these variables qualified by the classname rather than by implementing the interface.

I would tend to think of a set of constants differently to an enum.

Answer (score 0):

this link has an effective discussions covered http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=19221

and the bottom line is to avoid as possible as you can using constant only interfaces

Answer (score 0):

This solutions is not great, but sometimes is the best choice to have all constants gathered in one place, for example the translation keys used in application.

Using interfaces we can create a whole storage of those and do not duplicate them.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. I'd avoid that pattern whenever I could, not a good one at all in my book. I'd favour keeping the constants where they most make sense or where they belong from an OO perspective, and that's very rarely grouped together in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (besides the enum) would be a non-instatiatable class (private constructor) to gather the constants if an enum wouldn't fit (like strings, integers etc.).

Plus maybe make the class visible to the package only where it is used.