# conditional interface implementation

Tags: java, class, interface, locale

I want to ask if there is a possible way to conditionally implement interfaces or if there can be a workaround to what I want to do. I want to make two interfaces LangA and LangB that will only hold a very large number of final variables that are Strings used to print messages. As you probably imagine LangA is one language and LangB another one. What I want is have my message-handling class conditionally implement the interface needed based on the system's locale. I have no idea if this is possible at all in any way even with some custom ibrary, so if not, explain me if it can be worked around at least. (Quick question: is this possible in Scala? thanks!)
I have thought of a possible, but maybe not a very resource-efficient workaraound, which will have the class's constructor check the locale and set its own finals based on the values of some methodless class that will only feature the finals for each language (e.g. constructor learns that locale is locA so it sets finals myF1=LangA.myF1; myF2=LangB.myF2; etc.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface with only constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403392/interface-with-only-constants)

Comment: @duffymo I think not, because he is asking if the ConstantInterfaceAntippatern shall be avoided, whereas I am asking if I can conditionally implement an interface. Btw as far as the Antippatern goes, I have to implement the interface to more than one class, but for ease of explanation I refer to one class only!

Comment: I realize that.  You shouldn't do it, single or multiple classes.  Wrong all 'round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The *"class X implements interface Y"* relationship is fixed at compile time, and cannot be altered at runtime.

However, using interfaces to import constants into a class is a solution that dates back to Java 1.0. [This anti-pattern should not be used for new development](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Moreover, localization with compile-time constants is *not* a native solution in Java. You should [localize using resource bundles](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/).

If you need a way to switch implementations at runtime, replace constants with methods in your interface, and provide implementations that return different constants:

```
 interface Constants {
     double getAccelerationDueToGravity();
 }

 class EarthConstants implements Constants {
     double getAccelerationDueToGravity() {
         return 9.8;
     }
 }

 class MarsConstants implements Constants {
     double getAccelerationDueToGravity() {
         return 3.71;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I want to import the same list of constants to over 10 classes, I just referred to one, I know this is an Antipattern! Thanks for the quick reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not a good design.  If you have a large number of messages, you're better off storing them in a database and caching them in an object that lets you look them up in memory.

The idea of interfaces to hold nothing but constants has been discredited for a long time.

Interfaces should be about separating methods and behavior, not constants.

The idea that these are locale-specific points even more strongly to a database or a message bundle or - wait for it - a `Map` of `Property` values with `Locale` as the key.

If you must persist, you'll have a better chance with composition than inheritance.  You can inject an object with the messages it needs using a dependency injection engine like Spring's `BeanFactory`.

Anything other than the idea you posted.